# Adding custom project templates to GitLab

Tags: gitlab

When I tried to create a [new project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html) in [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/07/gitlab-10-8-4-released/) using templates I am provided with three options

```
* Ruby on Rails
* Spring
* NodeJSExpress
```

Is it possible to add a custom template in addition to the existing templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost! GitLab 11.2 will introduce the option to specify instance-level project templates, and 11.3 is currently anticipated to also add group-level project templates.

[gitlab-org/gitlab-ee#6860](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/6860) has a few more details. The [documentation page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/custom_project_templates) should be up sometime in the next couple weeks.